# Trying to retrieve parameter value from another class library

Tags: c#, ms-access, visual-studio-2013, class-library

**I have created Member Maintenance Code in which I will retrieve the members ID,Name and all basic things**
My code is as follows:

```
private void Mem_Maintenance_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        txt_mem_id.Text = Generate_no.gen_no("MEM").ToString();
    }
    catch(Exception Ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error\n\n"+Ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

**I have created a ClassLibrary named Library Whose code is as follows**

```
namespace LIBRARY
{ 
public class Generate_no
{
    public static int gen_no(string P_PRM_TYPE)
    {   OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\arekh\MS Access\soc_data.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
        connection.Open();
        int v_last_no = 0;
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        string query = @"select PARM_VALUE from soc_parm_mast where PARM_TYPE = '" + P_PRM_TYPE + "';";
        command.CommandText = query;
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();
        v_last_no = Int32.Parse(reader["PARM_VALUE"].ToString()) + 1;
        reader.Close();
        command.CommandText = @"update soc_parm_mast set PARM_VALUE = PARM_VALUE+1 where PARM_TYPE = " + P_PRM_TYPE + ";";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
        return v_last_no;
    }
}
}
```

But during execution an error is coming up

> System.FormatException:Input string was not incorrect format at
>   LIBRARY.Generate_no.gen_no(String P_PRM_TYPE)

Comment: Not an answer but - Please do not use string concatenation to create sql queries. It is susceptible to Sql Injections. Use [Parameterized Queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: I have tried it in other programs.It works properly.what is the problem with using concatenation.??

Comment: Ya it will of course work but as I just said... Sql injections - look it up

Answer (score 0):

```
command.CommandText = @"update soc_parm_mast set PARM_VALUE = PARM_VALUE+1 where PARM_TYPE = '" + P_PRM_TYPE + "';";
```

You were missing the single quotation marks in the update statement

Comment: I don't  think that will cause `System.FormatException`

Answer (score 0):

The Line `v_last_no = Int32.Parse(reader["PARM_VALUE"].ToString()) + 1;` causing the specified Error, The `Int32.Parse` will throw `FormatException` if the input is not convertible. So i strongly advise you to use `Int32.TryParse()`. Then the code will be like the following:

```
public static int gen_no(string P_PRM_TYPE)
{
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Connection string here"))
    {
        connection.Open();
        int v_last_no = 0;
        using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand())
        {
            command.Connection = connection;
            string query = @"select PARM_VALUE from soc_parm_mast where PARM_TYPE = @P_PRM_TYPE";
            command.CommandText = query;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P_PRM_TYPE", P_PRM_TYPE);
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();
            if (!Int32.TryParse(reader["PARM_VALUE"].ToString(), out v_last_no))
            {
                // Conversion failed, Show message if needed    
                // v_last_no will be 0
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = @"update soc_parm_mast set PARM_VALUE = PARM_VALUE+1 where PARM_TYPE =@P_PRM_TYPE";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P_PRM_TYPE", P_PRM_TYPE);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        } 
    }

    return v_last_no;
}
```

One more advise for you : beware of SQL Injection while using the Concatenated string as queries. Use parameterized queries instead.

Comment: Sorry Sir I am not able to understand what you are saying.. I am a beginner.

Comment: `if(!Int32.TryParse(reader["PARM_VALUE"].ToString(),out v_last_no))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error\n\n" + Ex.ToString());
                v_last_no = 999;
            }
            v_last_no = v_last_no + 1;`

Comment: Sir same error is coming up.BTW thanks for the help.